# MYSQL and this keeps popping up Error SQL query: MySQL said: Documentation #1054 - Unknown column 'id_D10' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

Please help! I have created a table in MYSQL and this keeps popping up Error SQL query: MySQL said: Documentation  #1054 - Unknown column 'id_D10' in 'field list' I just don't know what im missing

```
INSERT INTO
Department (dept_ID, dept_name, dept_branch)
Values
(D10,’IT’,’B100’),
(D20,’ADMIN’,’B200’),
(D30,’Sales’,’B300’),
(D40,’Marketing’,’B400’),
(D50,’Customer_Care’, ‘B300’)
;
```

Comment: `D10`, `D20` etc. are strings and need to be enclosed in single quotes

Comment: Tip: Don't store the 'D'